# Correct memory (and performance) management for large numpy arrays of images

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing, numpy

I am trying to transform a large number of images in this case the `shape = (42000,784)` and I am running into `MemoryError` when I do it repeatedly in my code (i.e. if I call the function scale_xy several times). I am running a 32-bit Python on a 16 GB RAM machine so I assume the error is due to the 32-bit architecture of Python. This is my code for the moment. I would like to avoid MemoryError and ideally not compromise on speed (i.e. by saving the intermediate step to disk for example). I know that calling for shape needs to load the array from memory so I tried to limit that in my code to no effect. Also if there is a way how I can do this faster, a suggestion would be very appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.transform as tf
import time

def initialize(data, img_shape):
    """
    Helper function to save some code to create arrays to be transformed.
    """
    shape = data.shape
    reshaped = data.reshape((shape[0],img_shape[0],img_shape[1]))
    new = np.zeros((shape[0],img_shape[0],img_shape[1]))

    return shape, reshaped, new

def batch_scale_xy(data, scale_x = 1, scale_y = 1, img_shape = (28,28),
             random = False, interval = (0.0,1.0) ):
    """
    Scales vectors in both x and y by given amount. If random is set to True
    it will randomly select values from uniform distribution on a given interval 
    for each individual image.
    """    

    shape, reshaped, new = initialize(data,img_shape)

    #All images are scaled evenly
    if random == False:
        for loc in xrange(shape[0]):
            new[loc,:,:] = tf.warp(reshaped[loc,:,:],
                                   tf.AffineTransform(scale=(scale_x,scale_y)))

    #Randomly scale each image by a factor
    elif random == True:
        for loc in xrange(shape[0]):
            scale_x, scale_y = np.random.uniform(low = interval[0], 
                                                 high = interval[1], size = (2,1))
            new[loc,:,:] = tf.warp(reshaped[loc,:,:],
                                   tf.AffineTransform(scale=(scale_x[0],scale_y[0])))

    new = new.reshape((shape[0],img_shape[0]*img_shape[1]))
    return new

X = np.random.uniform(low=0.0,high=1.0,size=(42000,784))

start = time.time()
new = scale_xy(X,scale_x = 0.5, scale_y = 0.5)
print "Time: %s seconds" % (time.time()-start)

start = time.time()
new = scale_xy(X,random=True, interval = (0.7,2.0))
print "Time: %s seconds" % (time.time()-start)
```

The error is as follows:

```
Time: 4.06599998474 seconds
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "preprocessing.py", line 100, in <module>
    new = batch_scale_xy(X,random=True, interval = (0.7,2.0))
  File "preprocessing.py", line 75, in batch_scale_xy
    shape, reshaped, new = initialize(data,img_shape)
  File "preprocessing.py", line 34, in initialize
    new = np.zeros((shape[0],img_shape[0],img_shape[1]))
MemoryError
```

Comment: Could you update your example code so that it is self contained and runable (eg replace the `load_data` method with something). I tried just using a empty numpy array but it didn't throw a memory error. Perhaps the dtype of my array was wrong and so the array was smaller? Regardless, an actual working example that shows the problem would be good :)

Comment: @three_pineapples I have edited the code and re-run it which gives me the the error after the second call of the `scale_xy` function.

Comment: Simplest suggestion: put a `del new` after the first iteration.

Comment: Do you know if iteration #2 would run without iteration #1 having run previously, i.e., perhaps it is the different parameters to scale_xy that cause additional memory usage.

Comment: Yep, I don't think there is much you can do beyond deleting the arrays once you are done with them. But if you need to hold onto the arrays from multiple calls to `scale_xy` you are pretty much stuffed. Any reason why you can't just use 64-bit Python?

Comment: You say you will compromise on speed by writing to disk, but did you benchmark the actual impact on execution time?  You should also be able to do this in parallel, using e.g. ``joblib``.

Comment: @three_pineapples I have to use 32-bit Python as I don't think 64-bit one is supported for use with `Theano` libary with GPU functionality enabled.

Comment: @mdurant I tried with no effect. In the end, I was able to resolve the issue by reducing calls to the function as three_pineapples suggested.

Comment: also came across this compressed in-memory solution for big arrays, may help: http://bcolz.blosc.org/

Comment: You might want to try getting it to work under 64-bit: http://pavel.surmenok.com/2014/05/31/installing-theano-with-gpu-on-windows-64-bit/

Comment: @three_pineapples thanks I will check it out whether I can get it to work!